# Working directory history

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

Say I have a repository with 5 changesets.

I run `hg update 1` to update the working directory to changeset 1.
I run `hg update 3` to update the working directory to changeset 3.
I run `hg update 5` to update the working directory to changeset 5.

At this point, is there a command I can run that will show me a history of the previous working directory changesets?  For example, a command like `hg updatelog` that would return the following:

```
changeset 5: 2013-05-21 16:46
changeset 3: 2013-05-21 16:08
changeset 1: 2013-05-18 08:32
```

I'm specifically interested in just the previous changeset, but a full history would be great too.  This would obviously be a local history since it would be different for every <strike>user</strike> instance of the repository.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Mercurial 2.6 there is the [Blackbox Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BlackboxExtension). Running:

```
hg blackbox | grep update
```

contains the information you were looking for.

It returns something like:

```
2013/05/22 10:02:48 user> update -r1
2013/05/22 10:02:48 user> update exited False after 0.09 seconds
2013/05/22 10:02:52 user> update -r0
2013/05/22 10:02:52 user> update exited False after 0.08 seconds
```